# Valid patterns for `zuul.ignored-services`

Tags: netflix-zuul

I'm using a Zuul gateway with Kubernetes service discovery agents. I have a few services like "my-service-1-bla" and "my-service-2-bla". Using the `zuul.ignored-services` property, I'd like to exclude all services ending in "-bla" from being dynamically added. Most online examples use "*" to exclude all services, and then add specific services one at a time. How do I exclude all services with post-fix "bla"?

This doesn't work:

```
zuul:
    ignoredServices:
    - 'my-ui' # this is excluded
    - '*-bla' # this doesn't exclude the "bla" services
```

Comment: Saw that a while ago when i was struggling with the same problem. We tryed many things and this seems like it worked for god only knows why, sorry it wasn't the solution for you :/

Answer (score 1):

The format of the properties were wrong. This works:

```
zuul:
    ignoredServices: 'my-ui, *-bla'
```

Enabling DEBUG logging on `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul` also helped to see what's going wrong.